# Programming a recursive method for summation from i to n

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying program a recursive method for summation from i to n for the following equation where f(0)=f(1)=1.

```
f(n) = from i = 1 to n ∑f(i-1) * f(n-i)
```

This is what I have so far, which is giving me a stack overflow error when n=4

Comment: Your recursive formula is the [catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), there's also a close formula to it

Comment: stack overflow error will rise as you might be giving a large 'n' as input

Comment: That should be `c(n-i)*c(i-1)` instead.

Comment: Probably you may add memoization to solve this problem for large numbers.

Comment: Do not use a global variable inside a recursive function. You change `i` inside the function so the expression `c(i-n)*c(i-1)` is not what you expect. Use a debugger or some print statements to see, how the values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to use recursion, your function would look like this:

```
static long catalan(int n) {
    return c(1, n);
}

static long c(int i, int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (i > n) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return catalan(i - 1) * catalan(n - i) + c(i + 1, n);
    }
}
```

Although, as others have said, a version that uses memoization will be much faster, this will be fine if you're doing it only for learning and testing.

- `if (n <= 1) return 1` is your base case.
- `else if (i > n) return 0` is to stop the sum when `i` gets greater than `n`.
- `return catalan(i - 1) * catalan(n - i) + c(i + 1, n)` is the summation, where `i` is increased by 1 until it reaches n.

Answer (score 1):

Your method does not match the equation you have provided. You state that:

```
n ∑c(i-1)*c(n-i)
```

but your final return statement is:

```
c(i-n) * c(i-1)
```

Perhaps you should try:

```
c(n-i) * c(i-1)
```

When I pass in 4 it generates the following call stack:

```
i = 0, n = 4
  c(i - n) with i = 1

i = 1, n = -3
  c(i - n) with i = 1

i = 1, n = 4
  c(i - n) with i = 2

i = 2, n = -2
  c(i - n) with i = 2

i = 2, n = 4
  c(i - n) with i = 3

i = 3, n = -1
  c(i - n) with i = 3

i = 3, n = 4
  c(i - n) with i = 4 becomes c(0) becomes 1
  c(i - 1) with i = 4

i = 4, n = 3
  c(i - n) with i = 4 becomes c(1) becomes 1
  c(i - 1) with i = 4 becomes c(3) and it repeats from this point on
```

So basically when `i` reaches 4 and you have an `n` of 3 you end up calling `c(3)` which then triggers calling `c(i - 1)` a.k.a. `c(3)` again and again.

If you make the change I suggested then the same invocation calls:

```
c(n - i) -> c(4 - 1)
  c(n - i) -> c(3 - 2) -> c(1) -> 1
  c(i - 1) -> c(1) -> 1
c(i - 1) -> c(1) -> 1
```

On the last line `i` has become 2 even though that is at the top level, due to the shared nature of that variable.

Comment: I have come up with the exact reason for the stack overflow error now! Was not what I originally thought.

Comment: So, using memoization will fix the SOE.

Comment: Well not really. The call to `c(3)` when `i` is 4 never actually returns. If your memoization doesn't include `i` then it leads to a drastically different algorithm.

Comment: Well, I'm just saying that using memoization may fix the problem. The implementation details are completely different ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive sum you will get something like this:

```
public int sum(int start, int end)
{
  if(start >= end)
  {
    return end;
  }
  return start +sum(start+1,end);
}
```

This scheme can be adapted to the formulas you want to use:

```
 static long c(long x)
  {
    if(x <2) return 1;
    return sumC(1,1,x);
  }

  static long sumC(long start,long current,long stop)
  {
      if(current>stop) return 0;
      return c(current-1)*c(stop -current) + sumC(start,current+1,stop);
  }
```

> 0 to 10 :
>   1
>   1
>   2
>   5
>   14
>   42
>   132
>   429
>   1430
>   4862
>   16796

Comment: I stopped at number 28 as it takes quite long to calculate. didn't get any StackOverflowExceptions

Comment: Use memoization, it will dramatically speed up this process.

Comment: You mean throwing the results of a c(X) into a list or map and see if it is already in there? Yes that would speed things up. I'll leave it to the OP to optimize this ^_^